# SQLite compare two tables and fetch the actual row

Tags: sqlite

I have two `SQLite` tables with same fields:

[image: Fields]

The first table named as `FB_Config_Trace` and the second `FB_Settings`.

`FB_Config_Trace` will be filled by the script to fetch the latest values from an configuration file, `FB_Settings` will be set by an user.

**Sample Data:**

**FB_Config_Trace:**

[image: FB_Config_Trace Data]

**FB_Settings:**

[image]

How i can fetch the latest rows/entries by given `Time`?

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join `FB_Settings` to `FB_Config_Trace` with a `LEFT` join like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.ID, s.ID) ID,
       s.Key,
       CASE WHEN c.ID IS NULL THEN s.Value ELSE c.Value END Value,
       COALESCE(c.Time, s.Time) Time
FROM FB_Settings s LEFT JOIN FB_Config_Trace c 
ON c.Key = s.Key AND c.Time > s.Time
```

Comment: The execution says an syntax error. And i misunderstand your idea.

Comment: `near "(": syntax error`. Really informative, yep.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss The query is syntactically correct: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=29424f4af3dd66387fed7e157bf916df Check the version of SQLite that you have. Window functions are supported by SQLite since version: 3.25.0

Comment: My environment using SQlite 3.2.1 and i cant change these.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Check the 2nd query in my edited answer.

Comment: Seems work (a little). Its not select the newest row.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss this condition: `NOT EXISTS (......c2.Time > c1.Time)` guarantees that the returned rows are the latest for each key.

Comment: If the Date on `FB_Settings` newer, the row will be listen, otherwise the result is empty. But i want to display the `FB_Config_Trace` here then.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss you should edit your question and clarify what you want with proper sample data for all cases.

Comment: Plese see the last image on the question. You have two tables (left image & right image). I want a result like simple `SELECT * FROM `FB_Settings` but compared/merged with the other table with only the newest entries (by datetime).